# How to run docker with experimental functions on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I have following question:

How to run docker with experimental features on (like image squashing `docker build --squash=true...` for reduce it size) on ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To turn on experimental docker functions create following file by:

`sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json`

and add below content to it

```
{ 
    "experimental": true 
}
```

and save file (by CTRL+X and Enter ) and exit. In terminal type:

`sudo service docker restart`

To check that experimental funcions are ON, type in terminal:

`docker version`

And you should see  `Experimental: true`

#### UPDATE

Instead of **nano** you can use this one-liner:

```
echo $'{\n    "experimental": true\n}' | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Comment: Note the limitations of that one-liner update:
It's trying to 'append' however if you actually already have a config file, it will break the file format.

Comment: sudo sh -c 'echo "$(cat /etc/docker/daemon.json) {\"experimental\": true}" |jq -s add |sponge /etc/docker/daemon.json && service docker restart'

Comment: fyi- to enable this for the client, the config file to create is `~/.docker/config.json` and the value is `"enabled"`, not `true`

Comment: Not sure, but I think `sudo service docker restart` will shut down any docker containers running, just be careful

Answer (score 18):

I tried everything here on a Ubuntu 18.04 VM on my mac--nothing worked. All over the interwebs said the same thing, but the one thing that finally got experimental turned on was [@Michael Haren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29/michael-haren)'s tiny answer:

> fyi- to enable this for the client, the config file to create is `~/.docker/config.json` and the value is `"enabled"`, not `true`

which meant something like this for me:

```
$ mkdir ~/.docker
$ echo '{ "experimental": "enabled" }' > ~/.docker/config.json
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
$ docker version
  ...
  Experimental: true
  ...
```

This should be a top-level answer. So, credit to them (except sweet internet karma points for me...).

Comment: This unfortunately did not work on Ubuntu 20.04, @Kamil's answer did however.

Comment: Note that the OP specified 16.04, so it may work in 16.04 or possibly was working at the time the answer was posted in 03/2020.

Comment: This is the top answer!

Answer (score 10):

If you only want to run it temporarily / without modifying files, you can `export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled`. The below turns on experimental mode for your client.

```
$ docker version
 Experimental:      false
$ export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
$ docker version
 Experimental:      true
```

Answer (score 2):

Posting this to help those who are running docker on macOS

You will need to enable experimental on two files, one is client while another is docker engine

I suggest open the file manually instead of direct echo into the file as that file might have some other configuration and you might not want to overwrite them accidentally

For client, visit `~/.docker/config.json`, and add `"experimental": "enabled"` on top level config as below

```js
{
  "experimental" : "enabled",
  "auths" : {
    "harbor.xxx.com" : {

    }
  },
  "credsStore" : "desktop"
}
```

For Docker Engine, visit `~/.docker/daemon.json` and add `"experimental": true` on top level config as below

```js
{
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  },
  "experimental": true,
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Do note that the "value" of `experimental` is different between client and server.

Once done, restart the docker using command below

```sh
killall Docker && open /Applications/Docker.app
```

then verify the result

```sh
docker version
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this on Linux using the `systemctl` as described by https://stackoverflow.com/a/70460819/433814 on this SO. However, first you need to edit the correct files... Here's the way to set it up in a MacOS if you were looking for similar answers.

## Docker run with Experiments MacOS

- Just set the variable `ENABLED=true` or `ENABLED=false` and this script will automagically turn it on or off, writing to the file

> **NOTE**: You MUST have `jq` installed to execute and update in-place.

```
ENABLED=true; \

CONFIG=~/.docker/config.json; DAEMON=~/.docker/daemon.json ; \

cat <<< $(jq --argjson V ${ENABLED} '.experimental = $V' ${DAEMON}) > ${DAEMON} ; \
cat <<< $(jq --arg V $(if [ "${ENABLED}" = "true" ]; then echo "enabled"; else echo "disabled"; fi) '.experimental = $V' ${CONFIG}) > ${CONFIG} ; \ 

cat ~/.docker/config.json ; \
cat ~/.docker/daemon.json
```

### Output confirmation

- This will be output automatically confirming

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {},
    "registry.gitlab.com": {}
  },
  "credsStore": "desktop",
  "experimental": "enabled",
  "currentContext": "default"
}
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": true,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
}
```

### Restart Docker Engine in MacOS

- Just run the following

```
killall Docker && open /Applications/Docker.app
```

#### References

- [JQ convert to number, convert to boolean when generating new json from shell variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814037/jq-convert-to-number-convert-to-boolean-when-generating-new-json-from-shell-var/54830801#54830801)
- [passing arguments to jq filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745451/passing-arguments-to-jq-filter/42576771#42576771)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo sed -i 's/ExecStart=\/usr\/bin\/dockerd -H fd:\/\/ --containerd=\/run\/containerd\/containerd.sock/ExecStart=\/usr\/bin\/dockerd -H fd:\/\/ --containerd=\/run\/containerd\/containerd.sock --experimental/g' /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).